# Getting a value from a ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

If I have this ConcurrentDictionary:

```
public class User
{
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public bool Owner { get; set; }
}

protected static ConcurrentDictionary<User, string> OnlineUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<User, string>();
```

Does anyone know how I would get the value of `Owner` if I already have the value of the `Context`? Basically I want to do a "find" using the `Context`. Thanks.

Comment: Could there be more than one User objects with the same Context, and if so, would you want to get all of them?

Comment: No. The Context is unique to each User. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a `Dictionary<string, User>` which, when given the context as a `string` will tell you which `User` it corresponds to.  If you are going to need to perform this lookup several times, and there isn't a problem using the additional memory, it may be worth creating such a dictionary.

If you are only going to be doing the search once or twice, or the mappings will be changing so often that you can't keep the dictionary up to date, then you can simply do a linear search on the dictionary using a `foreach` loop, or using a LINQ method such as `First` or `Where`, as demonstrated in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Does anything stop you from using standard Linq `FirstOrDefault()` method like so:

```
var item = OnlineUsers.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Context == myContext);
```

Comment: Well, you're doing a linear search on the dictionary, which more or less defeats the purpose of using a dictionary (although I don't think there's any choice without a redesign.

Comment: Well, the answer was assuming that the OP wanted a User object as the key for some other purpose and wanted to find out how to search for a value when he had just the context alone and not the whole object. But yes, you are right, if it can be redesigned, then it is the right thing to do.

Comment: As the problem is stated, I don't think there is an answer that will be better than linear. The Dictionary is keyed on User, not Context.

Answer (score 1):

How obout something like

```
var ou = OnlineUsers.First(x => x.Key.Context == "TADA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<User, string> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<User, string>();

dict.TryAdd(new User() { Context = "a", Ownder = false }, "aa");
dict.TryAdd(new User() { Context = "b", Ownder = false }, "bb");
dict.TryAdd(new User() { Context = "c", Ownder = true }, "cc");
dict.TryAdd(new User() { Context = "d", Ownder = false }, "dd");

IEnumerable<User> list = dict.Keys.Where(p => p.Context == "a");
```